Maximum number of edges such that $\nu(G) < \frac{n}{2}$
Given an even integer $n$. I want to find the largest number of edges in a $n$-vertex graph such that the matching number is strictly less than $\frac{n}{2}$. I believe that the maximum is obtained by taking $G = K_{n-1} \cup \{v\}$. Since $n-1$ is odd we have $\nu(G) = \nu(K_{n-1}) = \frac{n}{2}-1$.
Number of edges in $G$ would be number of edges in $K_{n-1}$, that is $\binom{n-1}{2}$. However, I have not been able to prove that this is in fact the largest number of edges. I have tried to do this by induction on the number of vertices but without much luck. Any help would be appreciated.

I think you basically already solved the problem.
You have shown an example with $\binom{n-1}{2}$ edges and $\nu(G) = \frac{n}{2} - 1$.
We only need to show that for any $n$-vertex graph with $\binom{n-1}{2} + 1$ edges, we can find a $\frac{n}{2}$ matching.

Divide the cases w.r.t. the size of the maximum clique.
Max. clique size $= n - 1$
Basically you have considered this, when adding any edges to $K_{n-1} \cup \{v\}$, we can find a $\frac{n}{2}$ matching.
Max. clique size $= n - t \leq n - 2$ with $t \geq 2$
We have a clique $K_{n-t}$ and $t$ remaining nodes.
The number of remaining edges outside $K_{n-t}$ is
$$
\binom{n-1}{2} + 1 - \binom{n-t}{2} = (t-1)(n-t) + \frac{t^2 - 3t + 4}{2}.
$$
Since by the assumption, $K_{n-t}$ is the maximum clique, each of the remaining $t$ nodes can only have $\leq n - t - 1$ neighbors in the $K_{n-t}$.
Let $V_{K}$ be the set of the nodes in the $K_{n-t}$,
let $V_t$ be the set of the remaining $t$ nodes, and
let $E_t$ be the set of the remaining edges between $K_{n-t}$ and $V_t$.
It is easy to see that we only need to show that we can find a $V_t$-perfect matching in the bipartite graph $G = (V_t, V_{K}, E_t)$, where
$|E_t| > (t-1)(n-t) + \frac{t^2 - 3t + 4}{2} - \binom{t}{2} = (t-1)(n-t-1) - 1$ (it is "$>$" instead of "$\geq$", because it is easy to see that $V_t$ cannot form a clique too, otherwise we can easily find a $\frac{n}{2}$ matching).
By Hall's marriage theorem, we CANNOT find such a $V_t$-perfect matching iff there exists a subset $V' \subseteq V_t$ such that $\text{Nbr}(V') \cap V_K < |V'|$.
Asumme such a $V'$ exists and let $s$ be the size of a smallest $|V'|$.
It implies that
$(t-1)(n-t-1) \leq |E_t| \leq s(s-1) + (t-s)(n-t-1)$, which is equivalent to
$$
s \geq n - t - 1.
$$
This is only possible when $t \geq n - t - 1$, i.e., $t \geq \frac{n}{2}$ (since $n$ is even).
I think it should be easy to start from here and show that the clique number must be larger than $n - t \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

Update
After a second thought, I think it would be much easier to prove that we must have a Hamiltonian cycle (more precisely, "hamiltonian cycle" minus "an edge").

See, e.g., Maximum number of edges in a non-Hamiltonian graph


One must add two edges to get a hamiltonian cycle. How would this help?

You can still have a perfect matching with "hamiltonian cycle" - "an edge".

So $\binom{n-1}{2} + 2$ edges entail a Hamiltonian cycle, and with one fewer edge, we still have a matching.

Indeed! I understand what you mean now

Glad to help :-)
